# Using Script Component in SSIS to Split Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, flat-file

Inside my `DFT`, I have a `OLE DB` Source that loads a large data set into my package. The data set has an integer column named `TYPE` which its value ranges between 1 to 200. Each type need to be loaded into a separate text file with its name (1.text to 200.txt, a total of 200 text files).

For example, for all records with type 125 a text file with name "125.text" will be created and all rows with type 125 go there. I know that this could be done with `Conditional Split`, but it will be ridiculously heavy. So, I just have to find a better way.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in a script transformation. You'll need to create the desired outputs and columns in the designer and redirect rows in the script as needed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136114.aspx.

Comment: Instead of creating 200 output ports, why not use the Script Component as a destination? Do all files have the same layout?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same layout. I don't want to have 200 FF destinations. That's why I'm looking for a Script Component solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code in C# in a `Script Component` and it is working.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{   
    string path = Path.Combine( "C:\\", Row.TYPE + ".txt");
    if (File.Exists(path))
        {
             using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@path, true))
                   { file.WriteLine(Row.Record);}
        }
    else
        { 
             File.WriteAllText(@path, "File HEADER  " );
             using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@path, true))
                   { file.WriteLine("\n");}
        }
}
```